# how to take on selected item from list view to autocomplete textview

Tags: java, android

I want to show item of list view in autocomplete text view when click on that item in the list view using the following code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

  LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
  GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


GoogleMap mMap;
SupportMapFragment mFragment;
Marker CurrentMarker,FindMarker;
Location mLastLocation;


CustomAutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces = null;
DownloadTask placesDownloadTask;
DownloadTask placeDetailsDownloadTask;
ParserTask placesParserTask;
ParserTask placeDetailsParserTask;

final int PLACES=0;
final int PLACES_DETAILS=1;
LatLng latLng;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    mFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mFragment.getMapAsync(this);


// Getting a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView
    atvPlaces = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
    atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);

    // Adding textchange listener
    atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Creating a DownloadTask to download Google Places matching "s"
            placesDownloadTask = new DownloadTask(PLACES);

            // Getting url to the Google Places Autocomplete api
            String url = getAutoCompleteUrl(s.toString());

            // Start downloading Google Places
            // This causes to execute doInBackground() of DownloadTask class
            placesDownloadTask.execute(url);


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });



    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);


 }

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}


private String getAutoCompleteUrl(String place){

    // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
    String key = "key=AIzaSyC_7RaIknbxXauB6n2xHNTZgRjg0eo5xog";

    // place to be be searched
    String input = "input="+place;

    // place type to be searched
    String types = "types=geocode";

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}

private String getPlaceDetailsUrl(String ref){

    // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
    String key = "key=AIzaSyC_7RaIknbxXauB6n2xHNTZgRjg0eo5xog";

    // reference of place
    String reference = "reference="+ref;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = reference+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        //Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
  //  mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
   // mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if(CurrentMarker != null){
        CurrentMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOption.position(latLng);
    markerOption.title("Current Position");
    markerOption.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    CurrentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));



    if(mGoogleApiClient != null){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResult){
    switch (requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {

            if(grantResult.length > 0
                    && grantResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(mGoogleApiClient == null){
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "permisison denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    String str = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_name)).getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this,str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private int downloadType = 0;

    // Constructor
    public DownloadTask(int type) {
        this.downloadType = type;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        switch (downloadType) {
            case PLACES:
                // Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                placesParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES);

                // Start parsing google places json data
                // This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                placesParserTask.execute(result);


                break;

            case PLACES_DETAILS:
                // Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                placeDetailsParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES_DETAILS);

                // Starting Parsing the JSON string
                // This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                placeDetailsParserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
 */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>>  {

    int parserType = 0;

    public ParserTask(int type) {
        this.parserType = type;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<HashMap<String, String>> list = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            switch (parserType) {
                case PLACES:
                    PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();
                    // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                    list = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                    break;
                case PLACES_DETAILS:
                    PlaceDetailsJSONParser placeDetailsJsonParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();
                    // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                    list = placeDetailsJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        switch (parserType) {
            case PLACES:


                String[] from = new String[]{"description"};
                int[] to = new int[]{R.id.place_name};

                // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
                //SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);

                // Setting the adapter
               // atvPlaces.setAdapter(lv);

                // list adapter
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, result,R.layout.list_item,from,to);
                // Adding data into listview
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                break;
            case PLACES_DETAILS:
                String location = atvPlaces.getText().toString();
                if (location != null && !location.equals("")) {
                    new GeocoderTask().execute(location);

                }

                break;
        }
    }


}

private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {
        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){
            Address address =  (Address)addresses.get(i);
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    address.getCountryName());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Find Location");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            FindMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(13).build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

    }

}

}
```

I want to show selected item in `autocompleteTextview` from listView when click on that item. Please tell me using my source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

        String str = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_name)).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this,str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        atvPlaces.setText(str);
       atvPlaces.dismissDropDown();



    }
```

Comment: ok,its working but crashed after show the data in autocompletetextview. searching not start

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                              at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:100)
                                                              at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:491)
                                                              at com.test.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:521)--i am getting this error

Comment: Please put your adapter code where you get nullPointerException

Comment: i m confused plz tell me where should i put adapter code

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this code, I modified.

```
String mSelectedItem;


    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int ClikedPosition, long id) {
                    //Getting clicked item from list view
                mSelectedItem=adapter.getItem(ClikedPosition);

//Setting to auto complete text view
                 mAutoCompleteTextView.setText(mSelectedItem);


            }
        });
```

Comment: If you want to send new data dynamically ,please create one function(ex: refreshAdapter(Arraylist list)) in custom adapter class and send that data through that function and call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: i want get from list to autocompletetextview.

Comment: Do you want to  get only one selected item from list view or more than one item?

Comment: i want only one item from listview  for search